# Mongo DB Remove Duplcates in a field in a Collection Javadriver

Tags: java, mongodb, indexing, mongodb-java

I am trying to remove duplicates in a collection using java driver in mongodb.
I am using the code

```
 table = db.getCollection("dummy_data_OLD");
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("url", 1)
    .append("unique", true).append("dropDups", true);
    table.createIndex(query);
```

It will create a unique index , but still duplicates present in the db. 
Is there any problem in my code?

Comment: What is this *table* thing in your code? Is it something similar to a collection? :)

Comment: @ Philipp that is the collection name

Answer (score 3):

This creates an index on the *fields* `url`, `unique` and `dropDups`. When you want to create an index using options, you need to provide these as a second DBObject.

```
DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("url", 1);
DBObject options = new BasicDBObject("unique", true).append("dropDups", true);

db.getCollection("dummy_data_OLD").createIndex(fields, options);
```

Comment: url is my field , but i what is this options ? how do i mention those things in my query?

Comment: url is my filed and what is this options ? how do  i give options in my query?

Comment: @CharlotteEden `Collection.createIndex` has [a two-parameter form](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/). The first parameter is a DBObject which defines the fields of the documents in the collection on which you create the index. The second DBObject defines options on that index, like `unique:true` or `dropDupes:true`. You need these two separate objects because `unique` and `dropDupes` are perfectly valid field names. Without the difference the database wouldn't know if you try to set options or create an index on said fields.

Comment: i just changed my code as like this 
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("product_url", 1);
BasicDBObject query2 = new BasicDBObject("unique", true).append("dropDups", "true");
      
  
  table.ensureIndex(query,query2);

Comment: i tried with above , but now i am getting this exception
com.mongodb.WriteConcernException: { "serverUsed" : "/192.168.11.107:27017" , "connectionId" : 324 , "err" : "too may dups on index build with dropDups=true" , "code" : 10092 , "n" : 0 , "ok" : 1.0}
at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:77)

Comment: @CharlotteEden This is a new problem for which you should ask a new question.

Comment: @CharlotteEden, +1 for correct answer, and yes, "code" : 10092  is another question